# how to update cache in two jvm running on two machine

Tags: caching

i  want  to know how to update cache between two jvm running on two machines .
I have sitution where requeste comes  and find in cache (we have to web server and one load balancer on top of these two), if found then return , if not found go to db and update the cache and return . At this point one cache  has update with new values , but the other server still have old values .  i want  to update other server cache with same  values . thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

You should ask the designer of your distributed system

Comment: unfortunately designer has left . and we have requirement  to create same cache on both server